# Basic user authentication works on Android, does not on iOS

Tags: android, jquery, ios, cordova

I'm building an app that gets data from a server using basic user authentication. This works fine on Android, but on iOS nothing happens. In safari it also works fine.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$.ajax({
    url: main_url+'api-cache/'+slug+'.json?r='+random_number(),
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(localStorage.getItem('email') + ":" + localStorage.getItem('password'))
    }
})
.done(function(result) {
```

main_url is a link to an https website.

I have als tried username and passwork like the jQuery documentation says and also beforesend, nothing seems to work. Without the authentication it works fine by the way. Also the result seems to be ".done" because no error is fired in ".fail".

Help? Oh and btw, I'm using Phonegap Build.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved using a couple of headers on the server instead of changing the app: https://benjaminhorn.io/code/setting-cors-cross-origin-resource-sharing-on-apache-with-correct-response-headers-allowing-everything-through/